# Tribute Project

Tags: javascript, html, css

l recently completed the freecodecamp tribute project and got 8/10.l fulfilled all the user stories, but l did add my own id attributes. l made a lot of mistakes and please assist in helping me correct them so that l can get 10/10. Also instead of using the html break tag, like l did on the last p tag with the id emphasis is there a CSS command l use instead.

```css
#main {
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  width: 1330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 2260px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

#title {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

#img-caption {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#img-div {
  width: 1300px;
  height: 680px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#tribute-info {
  /*max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;*/
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 550px;
}

li {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#emphasis {
  max-width: 550px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 420px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#tribute-link {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Object oriented Javascript Example</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main">
    <h1 id="title">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1>
    <p>The man who saved a billion lives</p>
    <div id="img-div">
      <img id="image" src="Dr. Norman Borlaug.jpg" alt="" />
      <figcaption id="img-caption">
        Dr. Norman Borlaug, third from the left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.
      </figcaption>
    </div>
    <h3>Here's a time line of Dr. Borlaug's life:</h3>
    <ul id="tribute-info">
      <li><strong>1914</strong> - Born in Cresco, Iowa</li>

      <li>
        <strong>1933 </strong> - Leaves his family's farm to attend the University of Minnesota, thanks to a Depression era program known as the "National Youth Administration"
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1935</strong> - Has to stop school and save up more money. Works in the Civilian Conservation Corps, helping starving Americans. "I saw how food changed them", he said. "All of this left scars on me."
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1937</strong> - Finishes university and takes a job in the US Forestry Service
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1938</strong> - Marries wife of 69 years Margret Gibson. Gets laid off due to budget cuts. Inspired by Elvin Charles Stakman, he returns to school study under Stakman, who teaches him about breeding pest-resistent plants.
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1941</strong> - Tries to enroll in the military after the Pearl Harbor attack, but is rejected. Instead, the military asked his lab to work on waterproof glue, DDT to control malaria, disinfectants, and other applied science.
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1942</strong> - Receives a Ph.D. in Genetics and Plant Pathology
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1944</strong> - Rejects a 100% salary increase from Dupont, leaves behind his pregnant wife, and flies to Mexico to head a new plant pathology program. Over the next 16 years, his team breeds 6,000 different strains of disease resistent
        wheat - including different varieties for each major climate on Earth.
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1945</strong> - Discovers a way to grown wheat twice each season, doubling wheat yields
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1953</strong> - crosses a short, sturdy dwarf breed of wheat with a high-yeidling American breed, creating a strain that responds well to fertilizer. It goes on to provide 95% of Mexico's wheat.
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1962</strong> - Visits Delhi and brings his high-yielding strains of wheat to the Indian subcontinent in time to help mitigate mass starvation due to a rapidly expanding population
      </li>
      <li><strong>1970</strong> - receives the Nobel Peace Prize</li>
      <li>
        <strong>1983</strong> - helps seven African countries dramatically increase their maize and sorghum yields
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>1984</strong> - becomes a distinguished professor at Texas A&M University
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>2005</strong> - states "we will have to double the world food supply by 2050." Argues that genetically modified crops are the only way we can meet the demand, as we run out of arable land. Says that GM crops are not inherently dangerous
        because "we've been genetically modifying plants and animals for a long time. Long before we called it science, people were selecting the best breeds."
      </li>
      <li><strong>2009</strong> - dies at the age of 95.</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="emphasis">
      <em>
          "Borlaug's life and achievement are testimony to the far-reaching
          contribution that one man's towering intellect, persistence and
          scientific vision can make to human peace and progress."<br />
          <br />
          -- Indian Prime Minister Manmohan Singh</em
        >
      </p>
      <p id="tribute-link">
        <h3>
          If you have time, you should read more about this incredible human
          being on his
          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug" target="_blank"
            >Wikipedia entry</a
          >.</h3
        >
      </p>
    </main>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So if l do that does that mean l can get rid of the #emphasis

Answer (score 0):

css provides a pseudo-selector called `:last-child`.

So, you could do add a style:

```
p:last-child {
    --style goes here--
}
```

Then the last `<p>` tag within a parent tag can have its own style.